# Detach/evict an entity long after session close (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, deserialization

1. An application is serializing "live" entities to the database (Ie. their proxies, session open).

   When eventually the app deserialize an entity, there's an open EntityManager and everyone 
   is happy.
2. *I can not do anything about the original application*, and the old app do not detach or evict the entity before serializing them.
3. Now I'm building a *new application* that also needs those entities (deserialize them from the database), but will treat them as DTO. This new app does not use Hibernate, so no open EntityManagers or Sessions are available.

   The entities can be of any arbitrary class, so I traverse their properties recursively using reflection.

   I'm getting a lot of LazyInitializationException. Properties that were not previously loaded are not really needed, so I just ignore those exceptions.
4. But the JSON libraries I tested (JSONSerializer, GSON) are not so forgiving, and break when trying to serialize the entity to string.

**Question**: How to tell the entity that it is detached, and should never try to load any property that is not already loaded? (Return null instead of LazyInitializationException.)

**EDIT** Please don't tell me to change the old application. I can't. The entities classes are sealed as they are now, because they are defined in the old app (which is still in use), and for this project I'm not allowed to change the legacy source code.
If the only answer is to start using Hibernate in the **new** application, please do say so.

Comment: Seems to me that you do not want GSON to serialize those properties in stead of trying to work around your gaping design flaws; I'd investigate the API to see if you can somehow make properties transient. I hope you will make the right choice and start to work with managed entities though.

Comment: I think it would be overkill to use Hibernate in the new app, because it only does simple queries, and do not ever persist any data in the DB. For now I'm simply excluding the problematic properties from the JSON serialization.

Comment: @Gimby, yes to the first point. Please elaborate about how to make properties transient without touching their classes' source code.

Comment: In stead of asking, check the API's documentation to see if it is possible at all. If not, tough break.

Comment: Please don't reply with RTFM, it isn't polite. As far as I can see, the only way to detach an entity is having a open hibernate session to detach from. I've asked because maybe someone knows something I haven't found yet.

Comment: Sorry you see it that way. I wish you good luck staying stuck.

Comment: Note: Maybe it's not obvious, but when I say "I can't find a way", that includes having looked at the jpa & hibernate APIs.
Anyway I'll simply continue catching the LazyInitialization exceptions. After getting them all, the JSON serialization Works. :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to look into making properties transient. But I want all properties to be serialized, just that them not throw LazyInitialization. My goal is/was to tell the entities that they are not connected any more.

Answer (score 0):

Your third point has a contradiction, you should not encounter LazyInitialization exception if you are not using Hibernate in your new app.
As regards to your question itself, since you are not using Hibernate, the entity goes back to being a POJO and you do not need to worry about LazyInitializationException. 
Can you give more information about the old and the new application that you were talking about. What kind of applications are those? 
Do they run on the same jvm or on different ones. I also do not understand the use of reflection in your usecase.

Comment: In fact I am encountering LazyInitialization exceptions. The entities come from the old app, deserialized from the database.

Comment: Both apps are stand-alone. They will not run at the same time. They "communicate" only through serialized objects in the database.
The new one will not change any data, just access them for reporting.

Comment: Reflection is needed because the new app go through the objects simply as data containers, accessing their properties recursively. Ie. There's no `(OriginalEntityClass)object`, only `object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()`.